# key binding isearch-forward with Greek keyboard

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, isearch, keyboard-layout

I use Emacs with various languages and have had trouble invoking `isearch-forward` from a keystroke when my keyboard layout (OS-level) is set to Greek. If I try the usual `C-s`, it says there is no binding for `C-σ` (since the 's' key is now the 'σ' key). I tried setting up a new key binding using `global-set-key`, switching to Greek, typing `C-σ`, switching back to English, and then indicating `isearch-forward`. This works fine for the first search, but I want to be able to hit `C-σ` again to search for the next occurrence, the way it works with `C-s` when my keyboard layout is set to English. But this doesn't work. Instead, it prompts me for a new search string. How can I set it up so that `C-σ` works exactly like `C-s`, so that I can hit `C-σ` again to advance to the next occurrence of my (Greek) search string? Of course I also want to do the same thing with `C-ρ` for isearch-backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding keys also in `isearch-mode-map`.  These keys are among those bound there by default, for example:

```
C-r    isearch-repeat-backward
C-s    isearch-repeat-forward
C-M-r  isearch-repeat-backward
C-M-s  isearch-repeat-forward
M-r    isearch-toggle-regexp
M-s r  isearch-toggle-regexp
```

For example:

```lisp
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-repeat-forward)
```

Instead of `(kbd "C-s")` you would substitute whatever key you also bound globally for Isearch.

---

You can see all of the `isearch-mode-map` key bindings if you load library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). Just use `C-h M-k isearch-mode-map`.

Comment: I tried loading the library as suggested, but got a "Cannot open load file no such file or directory" This emacs instance was complied locally from emacs-27.1.tar.gz. I tried with the version from the repository (this is Ubuntu 20.10), emacs 26.3, and got the same error. The file (neither .el nor .elc) is not in the lisp directory of either version.
.

Comment: However... I just tried putting both of the global-set-key assignments, in addition to what you suggested, into my .emacs and it appears to have solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "binding keys *also* in...". 

If this answers your question, and you don't get a better answer, consider accepting it. Questions with accepted answers are more helpful to others.

Comment: How do I do that (accept the answer)?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work